# Alternative to CGSPrivate API window transitions that are acceptable in the Mac App Store

Tags: cocoa, animation, window, core-graphics

I have written some code that makes use of the CGSPrivate API to transition between two windows. This is a private API and so Apple will not accept this on the App Store.

Is there a suitable Apple-accepted alternative to accomplish window transitions such as "flip" or "cube rotation"?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, I recently open-source a library that lets you animate windows around as layers. Hope it helps you out.

https://github.com/jwilling/JNWAnimatableWindow